# Python - Comparing strings and returning Booleans if they are equal

Tags: python, string

I want to do a function in python that takes 2 strings, and compare the positions. In case they are equal ('a' == 'a') it appends to a list True, and if it's not False. Also if there are more positions in a list, it should return False too.

```
def g22(S1, S2):
    new = []
    if len(S1) > len(S2):
        for i in range(len(S1)):
            if S1[i] == S2[i]:
                new.append(True)
            elif S1[i] != S2[i]:
                new.append(False)
            else:
                new.append(False)
    elif len(S1) < len(S2):
         for i in range(len(S1)):
            if S1[i] == S2[i]:
                new.append(True)
            elif S1[i] != S2[i]:
                new.append(False)
            else:
                new.append(False)

    return new
```

This is what i've came up with, but besides thinking it's wrong it's also sloppy.. ideas? Thanks

Comment: First what happens if both length matches?, you can solve this by adding "=" to one of both `if`.

Comment: do you mean compare the character at each position ? your wording is unclear

Comment: like this S1 = 'house', S2 = 'hose' would return [True, True, False, False, False] @amphibient

Comment: @RafaelAguilar you're right! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer without using `zip` (as per OP's request):

```
def g22(S1, S2):

    str_max = S1 if len(S1) >= len(S2) else S2
    str_min = S1 if len(S1) < len(S2) else S2

    new = [False]*(len(str_max) - len(str_min))
    new = [str_min[i] == str_max[i] for i in range(len(str_min))] + new
    return new
```

Hopefully `range` can be used!

Comment: You're the best, i'ma try it out!

Comment: @stasisOo made a minor change, should be bug free now!

Comment: Just used this format on another exercise with similar objective and it worked out great, kinda hard to do it without looking at your example though :p

Comment: @stasisOo Looking is not bad as long as you understand it and can adapt it to solve another problem. It is a natural learning process, so do not worry too much. Check also the other answers as well - there is a lot to learn from them!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def agrees(s,t):
    return [x == y for x,y in zip_longest(s,t)]
```

For example,

```
>>> agrees("mathematical", "mythical")
[True, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Note that `zip_longest` is `izip_longest` in Python 2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately i'm studying for an exam on python and zip wasn't taught so I can't really use it

Comment: @stasisOo Hopefully one of the other answers will be of better immediate use to you. If you go on in Python -- master `itertools` if you haven't already. It is often astonishing when a seemingly complicated question on Stack Overflow is easily solved in just a few lines using `itertools`. Good luck with your exam.

Answer (score 3):

Two basic suggestions:

1. The whole

   ```
       if S1[i] == S2[i]:
           new.append(True)
       elif S1[i] != S2[i]:
           new.append(False)
       else:
           new.append(False)
   ```

can be replaced with

```
        new.append(S1[i] == S2[i])
```

2. Instead of comparing the two lengths with an `if`, you could use `min(len(S1), len(S2))`. This will also fix your current problem of not handling the case when the two lengths match.

Two more advanced suggestions:

1. You could use a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) instead of an explicit loop.
2. You could use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) or [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to simultaneously iterate over the two lists.

Comment: map would be something like map(g22, S1, S2) where S1 and S2 are the strings ? I'm studying for a python exam i'm going to have, and wasn't taught zip() so i wont be able to use it. The problem for me with these exercices is mostly dealing with the False for the positions that don't have a match

Comment: however, do not forget that `S1[i] == S2[i]` will throw an `IndexError` in case of two strings of unequal length.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def compare(a, b):
    eq = [(x == y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
    rest = [False] * abs(len(a) - len(b))
    return eq + rest
```

Answer (score 1):

While I do like the compactness of John Coleman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41470511/1312080), you might be wanting to do it without using external libraries (for whatever reason or limitations), in core Python.

If so, one way to approach it is to write a generic function that compares the elements from the same index position in two lists, catching `IndexError` (when iterating through characters of two strings of unequal length) and assigning that comparison as *False* in that case:

```
def compareLists(argListA, argListB):

    size = max(len(argListA), len(argListB))

    result = []

    for i in range(size):

        try:
            comp = argListA[i] == argListB[i]
        except IndexError:
            comp = False

        result.append(comp)

    return result
```

Then your usage could be something like:

```
aStr = "Color"
bStr = "Colour"

#convert the strings into lists of chars

aList = []
aList.extend(aStr)

bList = []
bList.extend(bStr)

comp = compareLists(aList, bList)

print(comp)
```

prints:

> [True, True, True, True, False, False]

Answer (score 1):

So this is the code i've came up with using parts of all the answers

```
def g22(S1, S2):
    new = []
    if len(S1) >= len(S2):
        rest = [False] * (len(S1) - len(S2))
        for i in range(len(S2)):
            new.append(S1[i] == S2[i])
    elif len(S1) < len(S2):
        rest = [False] * (len(S2) - len(S1))
        for i in range(len(S1)):
            new.append(S1[i] == S2[i])
    return new + rest
```

Returns:

```
g22('casa', 'passa')
[False, True, True, False, False]
```

Thanks everyone :)

Edit: I find kinda dumb we can't use simple built in tools that would reduce this to 4 or 5 lines but oh well.